# Advantage of openParentApplication:reply:?

Tags: ios, watchkit

What are the advantages of doing calculations in `openParentApplication:reply:` instead of doing it directly in the WatchKit extension, aside of sharing data? Are there any performance differences? I assume code in `openParentApplication:` won't perform faster, because both the hosting app and the extension runs on the iPhone, right?

Comment: Why do you think that there are any advantages? Personally, aside from the data sharing, there shouldn't be any difference. As you said, both will run on the iPhone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The advantage is that you iOS app will actually stay open while completing the request. When creating a Watch App/Extension, you need to think about the lifetime of your App. Design everything to work even if your app is only open for 1 second. This does not give you the time to do the processing that you need for things like image processing, image caching, network requests, etc. Therefore, to make your Watch App as snappy as possible, defer all complicated processing to the iOS app, so that the next time the user raises their wrist for that next second, you will be ready and up-to-date.

If you did the all the processing on the Watch Extension, you can potentially never complete the network requests causing a terrible user experience. If the user raises their wrist to check for new info in your app, then see that it starts a network request, they will most likely lower their wrist for a bit then come back to the app seconds later. For battery consumption reasons, this kills your extension and your running request. When the user raises their wrist seconds later, they are going to be very disappointed to see the information is still out-of-date which will most likely cause them to lower their wrist even faster.

In summary, always try to have your data up-to-date and cached for when the Watch Extension actually fires up for that short amount of time.

Hopefully that helps shed some light on the difficulty of displaying snappy, dynamic information on the Watch App.